# Equilibrium state - System equal zero or limits

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose an ODE's system:

$\begin{cases}dx/dt=f(x,y,z,t)\\ dy/dt=g(x,y,z,t)\\ dz/dt=h(x,y,z,t)\\
(x(0),y(0),z(0))=(a,b,c)\end{cases}$

If I am asked to find the equilibrium points, I'll try solve:

$\begin{cases}0=f(x,y,z,t)\\ 0=g(x,y,z,t)\\ 0=h(x,y,z,t)\end{cases}$

But I've read at some texts that people say:

> For an equilibrium state $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ to exist, the following limits must exist:
> $$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=x^*;\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)=y^*;\lim_{t\to\infty} z(t)=z^*.$$

I'd like to know the differences and similarities between these two thoughts.

In particular, in some cases the limit exists, but equality does not.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your set of equations with limits appears to depend implicitly on initial conditions. I don't think this can be a full and exact transcription of what you've read.

Comment: @Ali, yes, it had initial conditions, I've tried to modify the question. Many thanks!

Comment: You seem to be describing two slightly different concepts of equilibrium. In particular the limit condition applies to stable equilibrium points only. However, $\dot x = \dot y = \dot z = 0$ also includes unstable equilibrium points, where the limits would only converge to them if $(a,b,c)$ were the equilibrium point, and the functions were constant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, now I see...! And $(a,b,c)$ must be at convergence region of $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ also, is it? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, $(a,b,c)$ must be in the region that converges to that stable point. Stable equilibrium  points at the bottom of troughs of the potential, while unstable equilibrium points are at the peaks, or at inflection or saddle points.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, maybe you could post your comments as answer. Thank you!

Comment: Since you believe that is sufficient I will. I wasn't sure if this was your concern at first, so only offered a comment for clarification.

Comment: Your comment answered my question, so feel free to post as a solution. Thank you!@PaulSinclair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was writing up my answer, I realized that my comment on the OP missed the actual difference between the two situations. Let me switch to a more general (and easier to deal with) notation than you have used: Given a map $F : \Bbb R^d\times [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R^d$, we are looking for curves $v : [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R^d$ which satisfy
$$\frac {dv}{dt} = F(v, t)\\v(0) = v_0 \in \Bbb R^d$$

In general the idea of equilibrium is a point that a solution $v$ will want to be at. Either it will stay at that point, or will approach it as time goes by. This is what the limit definition is getting at: $v^*$ is an equilibrium point if for some solution $v, \lim_{t\to \infty} v(t) = v^*$.

Any point $v^*$ for which $F(v^*, t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ will be an equilibrium state, since $v(t) = v^*$ is a solution to the differential equation, and obviously, $\lim_{t \to \infty} v^* = v^*$.

Some of those equilibrium points will be stable: if $v_0$ is anywhere near $v^*$, then $\lim_{t \to \infty} v(t) = v^*$. Some will be unstable: for any $v_0 \ne v^*, \lim_{t \to \infty} v(t) \ne v^*$. This does not change the fact that at $v_0 = v^*$, the limit is $v^*$, so the point is still an equlibrium point. And others will be semi-stable: for some $v_0$ near $v^*$ the limit is $v^*$, and for other $v_0$ near $v^*$ it is not.

But can there exist equilibrium points $v^*$ for which $F(v^*, t) \ne 0$ for an unbounded collection of $t \in [0, \infty)$? Yes. Here is a one-dimensional example:
$$F(x,t) = -x + e^{-t}\sin t$$
You can easily check that $v(t) = e^{-t}(v_0 - \cos t)$ is a solution. $\lim_{t \to \infty} v(t) = 0$. But $F'(0, t) = 0$ only when $t = \frac \pi2 + k\pi, k \in \Bbb N$.

The $-x$ term in $F$ pushes $v$ towards $0$, but the $e^{-t}\sin t$ term keeps perturbing it, so it can't settle down. But since that perturbance decreases with time, in the limit $v$ is finally able to converge.

So, $\lim_{t\to\infty} v(t) = v^*$ for some $v_0$ is what defines equilibrium points. Solving $F(v^*, t) = 0$ is a way of finding equilibrium points, but is not guaranteed to find them all when $F$ depends on $t$.

(If $F$ is well enough behaved and does not depend on $t$, then I think you can show that $F(v^*) = 0$ will give all equilibrium points.)

Comment: Sincerely, thank you very much for the excellent explanation.